# Configure exim4 on Debian

Tags: debian-lenny, exim

I've just configured exim4 using 'dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config', and it works as expected but there are several things i want to add to the standard configuration:

1. exim should allow incoming mail but only process outgoing mail for local requests
    (like sendmail or local connections).
2. i would like to forward some messages but i dont really get it with the router settings.
    if i have a list like this:

   `user@dom1.com : user@domx.com

   gateway@dom2.com : www-data

   *@dom2.com : asdf@domx.com`


    how can i get exim to process it?
   do dom1.com and dom2.com go to dc_other_hostnames or dc_relayhosts?
3. bevore delevering an email exim should boune it once and deliver it on the second attempt - if thats possible with exim.

Thanks in advance for any tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time but i found a solution:

1. exim comes secured out of the box
2. found my aswer here: [Multiple Domain Alias Files](http://koivi.com/exim4-config/) and dom1.com, dom2.com go to dc_relayhosts
3. exim doesent have that feature but there is a debian package called **greylistd** which does exactly what i wanted, found a guide to it but i cant post it because i dont have 10 reputation... google for 'exim4-clamav-spamassassin-greylistd-debian-etch-mini-howto'